# Python SSL Verification on Internal Network

Tags: python-2.7, ssl

I work for a corporation and want to have my script connect to my team's internal pages and pull data from them, and my script can connect to our external pages but anything internal returns an authentication error despite these same certs being used by my browsers.

What I use to gather the certs:

```
certfile = wincertstore.CertFile()
certfile.addstore("CA")
certfile.addstore("ROOT")
atexit.register(certfile.close)

#when looking at which certs are added, I see the ones I need to use are being pulled
```

How socket is defined and wrapped:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s,ca_certs=certfile.name, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)
```

Connection method:

```
def get_site(site):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(site)
    get_site.html = response.read()
    return get_site.html
```

Because I'm on windows, I'm using [wincertstore](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wincertstore) - but aside from that I wanted to figure this out without having to download additional modules for portability's sake.

When attempting to connect to an internal site, I receive this error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

My two questions are: 1) Is this something that would be invalidated on the server end or is this something that is likely to be on the client end?(or is that situational?) 2) If this is on my end, what am I missing to make this connect successfully on internal web pages?

I've read through the wincertstore, ssl, socket, and urllib2 docs but could not find anything referencing this scenario or other questions with people going through the same scenario, only some vaguely related questions but ultimately not useful in my case.

Comment: You don't provide any authentication information in your code which probably results in the `401 Unauthorized`. It is not clear what your application requires. But if authentication is done with client certificates then you have to provide these certificates with `certfile` and `keyfile` parameters to `wrap_socket`.